# Mathematica definition of Hermite polynomials: fractional index

Tags: special-functions

I am doing some calculations in Mathematica. I have solved a differential equation and noticed that the solution contains the Hermite polynomial $H$. The strange thing is that it appears as `HermiteH[-1/2, x]`.

[Here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HermiteH.html), you can find the documentation about this function. `HermiteH[n, x]` is the $H_n(x)$ Hermite polynomial. The problem is that I have always thought that $n$ must be a positive integer number. However, if you read the documentation, you see that Mathematica supports also the case for n to be a (possibly negative) fraction. What is the mathematical definition of a such a "generalized" Hermite polynomial? I was not able to find it anywhere. Is it some strange definition of Mathematica or do really such polynomials exist?

Comment: There appear to be extensions. See [the Wolfram functions site entry](https://functions.wolfram.com/Polynomials/HermiteH/), in particular integral representations and representations through more general functions.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/660663/hermite-differential-equation-non-integer-values-of-lambda. The classical orthogonal polynomials each satisfy a [differential equation](https://dlmf.nist.gov/18.8) depending on a parameter $\lambda_n$ for a nonnegative integer $n$; in this case the DE has a nontrivial polynomial solution. The formulas for the parameter are valid for non-integer $n$, but the DEs don't have polynomial solutions for such values. The DLMF treats the [Legendre functions](https://dlmf.nist.gov/14.2) but not the Hermite ones. I don't know any applications.

Comment: *Mathematica* uses [an expression in terms of the Kummer confluent hypergeometric function](https://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/HermiteHGeneral/02/) for evaluating non-integer order Hermite functions. But it is perhaps more natural to [re-express in terms of the parabolic cylinder function](https://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/ParabolicCylinderD/27/01/0003/).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When generalized, polynomials turn into functions. See [`Hermite Function`](https://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/HermiteHGeneral/02/)

```
HermiteH[ν, z] == 
    2^ν*Sqrt[Pi]*
      ((1/Gamma[(1 - ν)/2])*
           Hypergeometric1F1[
             -(ν/2), 1/2, z^2] - 
         ((2*z)/Gamma[-(ν/2)])*
           Hypergeometric1F1[
             (1 - ν)/2, 3/2, z^2]) // FullSimplify

(* True *)
```

Comment: What's more, if you set $\nu=-1/2$ and then `FullSimplify`, you get a modified Bessel function of the second kind: `E^(z^2/2)*Sqrt[z]*BesselK[1/4, z^2/2]/Sqrt[2*π]`.

Comment: @Roman - I believe that the simplification implies `z > 0`. See `FunctionDomain[#, z] & /@ {(E^(z^2/2)*Sqrt[z]*BesselK[1/4, z^2/2])/Sqrt[2*Pi], HermiteH[-1/2, z]}`

Comment: You're right, Bob. For $z<0$ the simplification is `1/2 E^(z^2/2) Sqrt[π] Sqrt[-z] (BesselI[-1/4, z^2/2] + BesselI[1/4, z^2/2])`. There are branch cuts in these Bessel functions.

Comment: Regarding the appearance of Bessel functions, it is well-known (to those who know them) that [parabolic cylinder functions can be converted to Bessel functions](https://www.math.ubc.ca/~cbm/aands/page_697.htm), and as I noted in a comment above, the non-integer order Hermite function is easily expressible in terms of parabolic cylinder functions.